# I want to align the text which is present in div tag in the center which is coming from $scope.Message.But not able to align it

Tags: html, css, angularjs

When I try to align the text in center, I was not able to do the text is coming to left. Did I miss anything?

```
 $scope.message = "Hello Stack Overflow";
 function abc(form){
                    $scope.message = "Hello Stack Overflow";
                    '<div align="center">{{message}}</div>'
                     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two different way

```
$scope.message = "Hello Stack Overflow";
function abc(form){
    $scope.message = "Hello Stack Overflow";
    '<div style="text-align:center;">{{message}}</div>'
}
```

or you can define a class and add style in stylesheet

```
$scope.message = "Hello Stack Overflow";
function abc(form){
    $scope.message = "Hello Stack Overflow";
    '<div class="text-center">{{message}}</div>'
}

<style>
    .text-center {
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to update following changes `("div style="text-align:center;")`

```
$scope.message = "Hello Stack Overflow";
  function abc(form) {
    $scope.message = "Hello Stack Overflow";
 '<div style="text-align:center;">{{message}}</div>'
}
```